# Matrix form in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a two dimensional array having elements of a matrix I want to display the content of the matrix on a edit control box while I am writting a dialog based project in VS2010
but the code I have added inside the button control 
is a s below.

```
void CtestCstrDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
 CString strTest(" "), strB,strC;
  // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
 for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
  strB.Format(L"%d ", j);
  strTest+=strB;
  }
 strTest+="\n";
 }
 m_edDisp.SetWindowTextW(strTest);

}
```

but I found that on runtime if I click on the button it only shows the content in a single line.
How to get the square form like

```
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3
```

?
Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `strTest+="\n";` with `strTest+="\r\n";`. Windows uses Carriage Return (ASCII 13, '\r') followed by Line Feed (ASCII 10, '\n') to designate a new line.

Comment: It was the most on to the point answer one can expect. Thank you Adams.